# PHP Pagination Script Not Showing Correct Content For Page Number

Tags: php, pagination, ceil

I've built a php script to navigate my blog pages back and forwards, but the first page shows up correctly, but when I navigate to the next page it shows the correct number, but still shows the same content as before. Then, the next button keeps showing the current page.

Here is my script:

```
$publication = "magazine";
$ppp = "6";

if(isset($_GET["id"])){$id = $_GET["id"];}else{
header("Location: ".$url."");
exit();
}

if(isset($_GET["currentpage"])){$currentpage = $_GET["currentpage"];}else{
header("Location: ".$url."");
exit();
}

$count_sql = "SELECT id FROM publication_posts WHERE publication = '".$publication."' AND issue = '".$id."'";
$count_res = mysqli_query($con, $count_sql);
$count_total = mysqli_num_rows($count_res);
//If None, Then Exit
if($count_total == 0){
header("Location: ".$url."");
exit();
}

$display_limit = $ppp;
$totalpages = ceil($count_total / $display_limit);//$rowsperpage
$currentpage = $totalpages;

$offset = ($totalpages - 1) * $display_limit;//$rowsperpage

if($currentpage == "0"){
header("Location: ".$url."/issue/".$id."/".$totalpages."");
exit();
}

$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM publication_posts WHERE publication = '".$publication."' AND issue = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$display_limit."";
```

Another thing that I notice here is that if I set the current page to `0`, it still shows `issue/id/0`, whereas this should redirect to the `$totalpages`

Anyone know where the problem is?

Here is my pagination:

```
<?php
// range of num links to show
$range = 0;
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
    // get next page
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page
    $link_next = "<a href=\"issue/".$id."/".$nextpage."\"><div class=\"pagiCell pagiNext fadeOut\"></div></a>";
}
else{
    $link_next = "<div class=\"pagiCell pagiNextX\"></div>";
}
?>
<?php
// range of num links to show
$range = 0;
if ($currentpage > 1) {
    // get previous page
    $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
    // echo forward link for next page
    $link_prev = "<a href=\"issue/".$id."/".$prevpage."\"><div class=\"pagiCell pagiPrev fadeOut\"></div></a>";
}
else{
    $link_prev = "<div class=\"pagiCell pagiPrevX\"></div>";
}
?>
<?php
    $link_refresh = "<a href=\"issue/".$id."/1\"><div class=\"pagiCell pagiRefresh fadeOut\"></div></a>";
?>
<?php
    $randpage = rand(1,$totalpages);
    $link_random = "<a href=\"issue/".$id."/".$randpage."\"><div class=\"pagiCell pagiRandom fadeOut\"></div></a>";
?>
```

Short URL : `localhost/publication/magazine/issue/1/1`
Long URL : `localhost/publication/magazine/issue?id=1&currentpage=1`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Please can you just answer the question. There is no user input into my script so injection shouldn't be a problem

Comment: If I see a security issue, isn't it a good thing that we point that out? And yes, you do have user input in your scripts. You inject `$id` which comes from `$_GET['id']` in your queries.

Comment: Do you have a solution to my problem - Of pagination? I can change the statements later. I just want to get this working!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Checking what the different variables actually contain before you use them? That way, it's usually quite easy to find exactly where it goes wrong. Since the above code doesn't contain a complete and verifiable example, we are dependent on you to have done all the possible debugging and that you include it in your question. Also, if we point something else out, just say "ok, I'll sort it" instead of getting an attitude. I'm simply trying to help.

Comment: Yes. The `ID` outputs the Correct `Issue` number, and `Currentpage` is `1`, but it's showing page `3`

Comment: So `currentpage` keeps being `1`, regardless of which page you're on? You need to show us the code you have for showing the pagination buttons, page numbers, the URL structure etc. There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: Ok. I've added the script for my pagination, and the url variables that I'm using too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your `$currentpage` var is a string and you are doing math with it without converting it. You should type cast it: [PHP: Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

`$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;`
becomes `$nextpage = (int)$currentpage + 1;`

Like Magnus Eriksson told before, you are not checking your user inputs for security issues. Testing your variables for expected values imply that, e.g. [PHP: is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Comment: Thanks kaoz, you're correct. It seems I'd coppied the script from a page without pagination, and therefore forgot to add in some extra code, which reads : `if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
}` - Working correctly now. Thanks again.